# Why the onmousemove event of javascript not working

Tags: javascript

Actually I want to create a "tagging" effect. But why when I click and drag on my image it create a "blinking" effect?I want to enlarge the div when I drag over the image

```
<html>           
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  var imgWrapper = document.getElementById("imgWrapper");
                    imgWrapper.onmousedown = function(event){
                         event.preventDefault();
                         var mouseY = event.layerY;
                         var mouseX = event.layerX;
                         var firstTagging = document.createElement("div");
                         firstTagging.style.position = "absolute";
                         firstTagging.style.top = (mouseY) + "px";
                         firstTagging.style.left = (mouseX) + "px";
                         firstTagging.style.border = "1px solid red";
                         imgWrapper.appendChild(firstTagging);

                         imgWrapper.onmousemove = function(event){
                             firstTagging.style.width = (event.layerX - mouseX) + "px";
                            firstTagging.style.height = (event.layerY - mouseY) + "px";


                         }

                    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="imgWrapper">
<img src="jlin.jpg">
</div>
</body>     
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jPkpR/

But if I use onmousemove on image, it works fine, why?
http://jsfiddle.net/jPkpR/1/

Comment: try using `pageX` and `pageY` instead of `layerX` and `layerY`. Do not know why it works.

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/2cRRu/

Comment: it still blinking on chrome and firefox

Comment: I do not know. in my chrome it works ok. (I am on Ubuntu). Sorry, do not have any more ideas. Do you mean that the dimensions of the rectangle sometimes are smaller than where the mouse is?

Comment: ya, it look like it always moveback and forth, u can check the second link i provided it works well

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with calculating the size of #imgWrapper. When `onmouseover` gets fired the height and width of #imgWrapper child element (`firstTagging`) is changing. This force browser to:

- recalculate #imgWrapper width and height
- fire the onmouseover event

This may repeat multiple times.

It is working good while the event is on image because image size is no changing.

As a fast solution you can add:

```
#imgWrapper {
   overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Which will force the #imgWrapper size to be fixed.